# How to fix the memory usage when using VGG16 or VGG19 models in python?

Tags: python, keras, memory-leaks, vgg-net

I am using a `VGG16` and `VGG19` models to create keywords (tags) related to an image, when using the `generate_keywords` function once everything works flawlessly but my program needs to call that function multiple time on different pictures and this results in the RAM getting filled and the system killing the process

```
def generate_keywords(image_path):
    # Load the pre-trained VGG16 model
    model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')

    # Load and preprocess the image
    img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = preprocess_input(x)

    # Use the model to predict the most likely object labels for the image
    preds = model.predict(x)
    labels = decode_predictions(preds, top=5)[0]

    # Extract the labels from the prediction and return them as a set
    keywords = set()
    for label in labels:
        keywords.add(label[1].lower())
    return keywords
```

I ran the python program with `valgrind` and I noticed some memory leaks, most likely from the models them selves but I can't confirm this however I did see some github conversation and issues about this but none provided a fix or a workaround to this problem

Note: I am running the script on a Pi 4

Things I tried:
`tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` but this does not seem to have an effect on the memory usage
`reset_states()` this also does not affect the memory usage

Comment: Basic optimization is to load the model once, not for each function call.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I moved the `model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')` outside the function but the process still gets killed